# Image Not Displaying When Looking At Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get an image to display when the player is looking at the object of which the script is attached, and in contact with its box collider trigger. The image is a component of the object named "interactImage" and I intend on displaying it to the user by disabling/enabling it's "canvas" component. You can see the script below:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class interactText : MonoBehaviour

{

bool isLook;
bool isCollide;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    if (isCollide == true && isLook == true)
    {
            GameObject.Find("interactImage").GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = true;
    }

}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collide)
{
    isCollide = true;
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider collide)
{
    isCollide = false;
    GameObject.Find("interactImage").GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = false;
}

void OnBecameVisible()
{
    isLook = true;
}

void OnBecameInvisible()
{
    isLook = false;
    GameObject.Find("interactImage").GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = false;
}
}
```

This script, simply put, does not display. When the player triggers and looks at the object, the image does not display in the camera's view. I don't know why. Any thoughts?

Comment: The single `&` in `isCollide == true & isLook == true` should be `&&`.

Comment: @sowa typo, which I have corrected. The script doesn't work at all.

Comment: Did you check if `OnTriggerX` and `OnBecame(In)Visible` run? Like put a Debug.Log in all of them and check the console.

Comment: Further I recommend caching a reference to the canvas in `Start()` by saying `canvas = transform.GetComponentInChildren<Canvas>();` and having a `Canvas canvas;` field.

Comment: Are your colliders marked as Triggers? And is there a RigidBody on at least one of the colliding objects?

Comment: @sowa yes they are marked as triggers. PS the interacting player is a rigidbody.

Comment: So I cached the reference and checked if functions were running. The script works for one object, there is nothing special about that object, it's exactly like the other in that it has a trigger collider and the script is of course added. But it does appear that the OnBecameVisible() function is not working for the other object hence preventing the image from displaying. That's odd. Any ideas?

Comment: The script is attached to each of those objects?

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, the gameobject needs a renderer in order to work.